# Ruby method to sum all values in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to sum the elements of an array. WITHOUT using flatten. I have tried using the following:

```
def multi_array_sum(arr)
  sum = 0
  arr.each do |row|
    row.each do |column|
      sum += column
    end
  end
  return sum
end
```

but unfortunately, it is not working. I am not sure how to iterate though a multidimensional array considering that I cannot use `each` if the first element in the array is not another array itself, for example, `array = [[1, [1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`.

Comment: In what sense is `array = [[1,[1,2],[3,4,5]]` an nxn array? What is the value of `n` here?

Comment: your array is invalid

Answer (score 8):

If all elements are numeric or arrays, and you want to sum them all:

```
array.flatten.inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use standard array functions and then enumerable.

```
array.flatten.reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% sure that you cannot use `flatten` then you can use:

```
array.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }.reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you absolutely can't use flatten (which is a bit weird), you can use a simple recursive method:

```
def multi_array_sum(arr)
  case arr
    when Fixnum
      arr
    when Array
      arr.reduce(0) { |agg, sub_arr| agg + multi_array_sum(sub_arr) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If each inner array is the same size and contains only numbers, you could use the method [Matrix#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D) to convert the array to a matrix, [Matrix#each](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each) (without a block) to create an enumerator to generate the elements of the matrix, and [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) to compute the sum of all elements of the matrix.

```
require 'matrix'

def sum_all(arr)
  Matrix[*arr].each.reduce(:+)
end

sum_all [[1,2],[3,4]] #=> 10
```